# Take part of text and convert into date

Tags: excel, vba

Attempting to remove the "As Of : " part of "As Of : 07/31/2015" and convert the remaining text into a date. So far I have:

```
Sub FasFormat()
Dim period As Long
    period = Mid([B4], 8, 10)
    period.Value = CDate(period)
    [B4] = period
End Sub
```

But I get an invalid qualifier error. Drawing a serious blank

Comment: `[B4] = CDate(Mid([B4], Len("As Of : ") + 1))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. (I've substituted my own variable date here!)

```
Dim period As String
Dim Strmydate As String
Dim mydate As Date

    Strmydate = "As Of: 07/31/2015"
    period = Mid(Strmydate, 8, 10)
    mydate = CDate(period)
    MsgBox period
```

Comment: This seems to be only returning it as plain text? Not sure why

Comment: You need to specify the Number format of the cell e.g. Sheet1.Range("B4", "B200).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd" .. or whatever date format you want

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FastFormat()
Dim period As String
    period = Mid([B4], 8, 11)
    ' you can also use 
    ' period = Trim(Right([b4], Len([b4]) - WorksheetFunction.Search(": ", [b4])))
    period = CDate(period)
    [B4] = period
End Sub
```

Changing the `period` to String and removing the `.Value` fixes the issue - it returns a date. Note I also extended the `mid()` to `11`.

Also, if these are all in a column, you could do Text To Columns, avoiding VBA altogether.  Just highlight the cells, go to Data --> Text to Columns, and use `:` as a delimiter.